# Mode.scope.first instead of Model.scope[0] - why we have so different execution time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two simular codes:

**1 code:**

```
User.chats.first  // execution time 17 SEC!
```

**2 code**

```
User.chats[0] // execution time is 2 ms
```

SQL log - 1 code:

```
    **(17018.8ms)**  SELECT  "chats".* FROM "chats" WHERE "chats"."user_id" = $1 AND 
("chats"."blocked" = 'f' OR "chats"."blocked" IS NULL) ORDER BY "chats"."id" ASC LIMIT $2
```

SQL log - 2 code:

```
    **(2.2ms)**      SELECT "chats".* FROM "chats" WHERE "chats"."user_id" = $1 AND 
("chats"."blocked" = 'f' OR "chats"."blocked" IS NULL) ORDER BY "chats"."id" ASC
```

What is diffirent beetwen first method and [0]?

Why execution speed so different 17 sec and 2 ms?

Comment: Pretty sure they're the same. Did you run those in rails console right? The second time it might have used the cache. Start a new console and run User.chats[0] first see what time you get.

Comment: I agree with @razvans. Rails and ActiveRecord cache the query after the first time as an auto optimization. If you really want to test this, I would time it once, exit the console, reenter and the time the second. Otherwise your data is skewed bc of the caching. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/rails-activerecord-caching/

Comment: I agree with the other fellows. Try running `User.chats[0]` first and `User.chats.first` after that. See what happens.